# Test a text field with dynamic value

Tags: selenium, selenium-ide

Is there a test command or set of commands that will test a text field with dynamic value. F.e., the text field value is *textText 10001 textTextText*. But on the next run of the test suite, the value will be *textText 10002 textTextText* and it's going to increment on every run.

So, I am going for one of the following options:

1. check only part of the value of the text field
2. set a dynamic check (if possible)

I am using Selenium IDE 2.4.0 in Mozilla Firefox.

Comment: What framework are you using to write the tests? This is not a Selenium question

Comment: @RobbieWareham - I am using Selenium IDE 2.4.0

Comment: if you are using the IDE, it's most likely going to be a more difficult goal to be reached.  however, without a practical example of what you want it's difficult to provide any solutions for this question

Comment: @sircapsalot - ehm... I just gave an example of what the case is and what I want. I don't have any other examples of this being done.

Comment: @Syspect - You need to make the fact that it is IDE clear.  The question is tagged with Selenium only.  As a Selenium question, it does not make sense.  It only has context if it is tagged with Selenium IDE as well